# get redirect link from different site

Tags: http-redirect

What tool can I use to open the pages I want indirectly with another site? For example, how can I create a redirect link through https://cse.google.no or https://maps.google.com.ai, for example: https://maps.google.com.ai/url?sa=t&url=https://www.kokyworld.com
I need it for using seo and get redirect backlink. It means to be transferred to the desired page after a few seconds through different sites